# VS2010 Express For WP and XCode project.pbxproj file

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7

Can anyone tell me what is the Visual Studio 2010 Express For Windows Phone equivalent file to XCode project.pbxproj ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the pbxproj is the project file. There are a couple differences here to be aware (but not too many). The simple answer to your question that the .csproj file is the project file equivalent.

You can also bundle multiple projects together into a .sln. (BTW, if you open a .csproj with Visual Studio, it normally creates a .sln for you.. lot's of things like Source control are handled in the .sln file)

I'm not really sure why you care that much about which is the project file though as Visual Studio should take care of much of the work for you. Be careful with this file. You can edit it (as it is just an XML file), but I wouldn't recommend doing that until you really understand what is going on...

PS. vote for this answer if it helped you.. I would like to build up my reputation a little..

Answer (score 0):

There are two files, namely, .sln file, i.e. the solution file, and one or more .csproj /.vbproj files, i.e. the project file(s), that provide the equivalent functionality. Together they define what is included in the project, build configuration and how to build them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to mark this too as the answer to my question. But only one can be marked as answer to the question. :)